# The original file 'AndroidManifest.xml' has been deleted or is not accessible

Tags: android, android-manifest

Well. I have imported a project into my eclipse and now whenever I save an xml file, this popup comes up, like "**The original file '*.xml' has been deleted or is not accessible.**" I have cleaned and fixed my project several times but no use.

Anyone solved this issue?

Comment: I'm getting this message almost constantly, the files exist on my hdd but eclipse won't save them.. completely confused

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try restarting Eclipse. I had same error message but I didn't do anything special like import a project - I've restarted Eclipse and it's working, for now.

Comment: It is working for me too, but don't know why it happens like this, If any one explain why so will be appreciated.

Comment: I had the same problem with a pom.xml file. The other pom.xml files in my other projects were fine, just this one was in this funky state. I checked in local history as suggested below and there was nothing there. I could overwrite the file just fine but every time I saved I got this message. Restarting eclipse worked for me.

Comment: @crowmagnumb yes - restarting Eclipse worked for me, too. In my case though it was a pom.xml file as well. The reason it started causing trouble is, that I removed a project, renamed the folder and imported it again. That's when the trouble started. Restarting Eclipse helped (I assume there was some sort of cache for the local history causing trouble).

Answer (score 1):

## Local History

Right click on your project and say replace from local history. If you've deleted the file, you'll find it in history.

**OR**

Can you go to your workspace->your project folder and see if there is a manifest there?

Comment: Thanks, that worked! The restart Eclipse did not work. The Manifest was not in my file folder, but I was able to right click on my project and select `Restore from Local History`, and it was right there. However it erased the changes I made, but that's ok, I re-added them.